# PHP, inserting CSV from external source into MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I know this has been asked before -- I tried to read previous Q&A on the topic but I'm still stuck. Probably I read too many Q&A and have a bad mix of techniques as a result.

I don't get an error, I just don't get anything in my table. The echo $i is to help debug and I only ever get a 0 rather than expected 0 1 2 3 ... N rows.

My DB connection credentials are all fine I use them all over my site for Select statements.

```
    $csv_file = str_getcsv("https://ds.data.jma.go.jp/tcc/tcc/products/gwp/temp/list/csv/year_wld.csv"); 
    $csvfile = fopen($csv_file, 'r');
    $theData = fgets($csvfile);
    $i = 0; 

while (!feof($csvfile))
{
    echo $i;
   $csv_data[] = fgets($csvfile, 1024);
   $csv_array = explode(",", $csv_data[$i]);
   $yrr = $csv_array[0];
   $vals= $csv_array[1]; 
   $sql1 = "INSERT INTO Table1(Year,Value) VALUES(" .  $yrr . "," . $vals. ")";
   $conn->query($sql1); 
   $i++;
}
```

Comment: There is nothing in your code that would make php display php or mysql errors, so no wonder you do not see any...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem here is the fact that you are trying to open a text variable as a file:

```php
$csvfile = fopen($csv_file, 'r');
```

In fact you already have an array from from `str_getcsv` so your whole code should look like (if you can read the whole file at once):

```php
$csvFile = array_map('str_getcsv', file("https://ds.data.jma.go.jp/tcc/tcc/products/gwp/temp/list/csv/year_wld.csv"));
array_shift($csvFile); //we remove the headers
$i = 0;

/**
 * Removes all the "*" and "+" symbols as I assume that you want a float since you are not wrapping it in the sql query
 */
function removeUnwantedChars($string) {
    return preg_replace('/[^0-9\\.\\-]/i', '', $string);
}

foreach($csvFile as $csvData) {
    echo $i++;
    $yrr = $csvData[0];
    $vals = removeUnwantedChars($csvData[1]); 
    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO Table1(Year,Value) VALUES(" .  $yrr . "," . $vals. ")";
    $conn->query($sql1); 
}
```

If you cannot read it all at once then I suggest to first download the file line by line:

```php
<?php
$url = "https://ds.data.jma.go.jp/tcc/tcc/products/gwp/temp/list/csv/year_wld.csv";
$fileHandle = fopen($url, "r");

/**
 * Removes all the "*" and "+" symbols
 */
function removeUnwantedChars($string) {
    return preg_replace('/[^0-9\\.\\-]/i', '', $string);
}

$i = 0;
$headersSkipped = false;
while ($csvData = fgetcsv($fileHandle)) {
    if (!$headersSkipped) {
        $headersSkipped = true;
        continue;
    }

    echo $i++;
    $yrr = $csvData[0];
    $vals = removeUnwantedChars($csvData[1]); 
    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO Table1(Year,Value) VALUES(" .  $yrr . "," . $vals. ")";
    $conn->query($sql1); 
}

fclose($fileHandle);
```

Yet like said by @Shadow above it is always great to be more verbose. So in case `query` returned `false` then it would be great to output the last error (if you are using PDO then `errorInfo()` function.